# Admob: Display ads in an APK app that is not uploaded to Google Play Store

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob, ads

I know there are a few posts with the question here, but they all are totally outdated.

---

I have an Android app that is not available in the Google Play Store. Instead, it is only available for download from our website as an APK file.

Is it possible to show Admob ads in the app?

If so, how does it work with for example the app-ads.txt requirements?

---

## EDIT:

Thanks. But what if I have it on both, the Play Store and as an APK download from my website. Will Admob also display ads in the APK-version of the app? Or only if users download it from the PlayStore (or a different supported app store)?

Comment: you cannot display advertisement without listing on supported app stores (not necessary play store). Refer to this link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have it on both, the Play Store and as an APK download from my website. Will Admob also display ads in the APK-version of the app? Or only if users download it from the PlayStore (or a different supported app store)?

Comment: i have seen advertisements in apk based app install ( i.e. install apk outside of play store ). But i really don't know if admob internally checks for source of install and puts limit on the ad display for invalid traffic in that case?. I think you should connect with admob team to validate it.